# Google Data Studio Connector Get Report URL

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

When someone goes to a data studio connector and creates a new report, that data studio report is saved in their Google Drive. Is there a way to programmatically get a link to that report from the apps script code, like other Google Drive integrations?

For example, Google Sheets plugin would need:

```
var sprURL = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
Logger.log(sprURL.getUrl());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported.